# Getting the month from different Date formats in R

Tags: r

I am trying this code and figuring out why in the second instance I am not getting the month of the Date.

```
event_text <- c("7-May","Aug-89")

month(strptime(event_text[1], format = "%d-%b"))

5 #fine

month(strptime(event_text[2], format = "%b-%y"))

NA #not fine
```

Comment: Not an answer, but it seems that the day component is required here.

Comment: yes it does:event_text <- c("7-May","1-Aug-89")
> strptime(event_text[2], format = "%d-%b-%y")
[1] "1989-08-01 EDT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `month.abb` and some regex:

```
> months <- gsub("\\d+|\\-", "", event_text)
> which(month.abb %in% months)
[1] 5 8
```